# how to call member function of a derived class without downcasting

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I have a hirerchy of Message class and Processor class. Each processor can recieve one or more messages on the fly. As each message can have some differnt attributes, I've to downcast that message to the concrect message class, to actually process that.
  As there are a no. of message classes and process classes, I don't want to use dynamic_cast.
I tried to use following code, but this is giving compile time error.
Also, I have the flexibility to attach a processor pointer with a message (if needed), but not the other way round.

```
class Message  
{  
    public:  
    virtual const Message* const getMessage() const = 0;
};

class MA : public Message  
{  
    public:  
    const MA* const getMessage() const {return this;}
    void printMA() const{std::cout<<"I am MA"<<std::endl;}
};

class MB : public Message  
{  
    public:  
    const MB* const getMessage() const {return this;}
    void printMB() const{std::cout<<"I am MB"<<std::endl;}
};

class Processor  
{  
public:  
    virtual void process(const Message* m) = 0;

};

class PA : public Processor  
{  
    public:  
    void process(const Message* m) {processM(m->getMessage());}

    void processM(const MA*  m) {m->printMA();}
    void processM(const MB*  m) {m->printMB();}
};

int main()  
{  
    Message* m1 = new MA();  
    Message* m2 = new MB();  

    Processor* p1 = new PA();  
    p1->process(m1);
    p1->process(m2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you have to cast, then something in the design is wrong

Comment: Why can't you have a common method say print in the Message based classes and that is called from Processor?

Comment: the print methods here are just for example. I actually have different attributes and methods in the each derived message class, which are not feasible (and i don't think correct too) to put in the base class.

Comment: @puneetagrawal So, you are having data inheritance, I presume? You could use templating then, Processor<TMessage> with specializations for Processor<MA>, that can access members of MA without casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used 'double dispatch' finally to get around this. Now, the only thing is that I need to add a function in MessageProcessor' class, whenever i add a new message type., but i think that is fine.

```
class MessageProcessor
{
    public:
        virtual void process(const MA*) const{std::cout<<"unhandled:MA"<<std::endl;}
        virtual void process(const MB*) const{std::cout<<"unhandled:MB"<<std::endl;}
        virtual void process(const MC*) const{std::cout<<"unhandled:MC"<<std::endl;}
};

class Message
{
    public:
    virtual void process(const MessageProcessor*) const = 0;
};

class MA : public Message
{
    public:
    void printMA() const{std::cout<<"I am MA"<<std::endl;}
    virtual void process(const MessageProcessor* p) const {p->process(this);}
};

class MB : public Message
{
    public:
    void printMB() const{std::cout<<"I am MB"<<std::endl;}
    virtual void process(const MessageProcessor* p) const {p->process(this);}
};

class MC : public Message
{
    public:
    void printMC() const{std::cout<<"I am MC"<<std::endl;}
    virtual void process(const MessageProcessor* p) const {p->process(this);}
};

class Processor : public MessageProcessor
{
    public:
    void processM(const Message* m){m->process(this);}

};

class PA : public Processor
{
    public:
    void process(const MA*  m) const {m->printMA();}
    void process(const MB*  m) const {m->printMB();}
};

class PB : public Processor
{
    public:
    void process(const MA*  m) const {m->printMA();}
    void process(const MC*  m) const {m->printMC();}
};

int main()
{
    const Message* m1 = new MA();
    const Message* m2 = new MB();
    const Message* m3 = new MC();

    Processor* p1 = new PA();
    p1->processM(m1);
    p1->processM(m2);
    p1->processM(m3);

    Processor* p2 = new PB();
    p2->processM(m1);
    p2->processM(m2);
    p2->processM(m3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, if only a few message types need special processing and the rest can all use the same code you can have a process(const Message*) in your MessageProcessor, and anything that doesn't have a specialized process() will use that. Of course, if each message type needs its own handler, then of course you'll need to add a new function for each new message type.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is eliminate the `getMessage()` method, and make the `print()` pure virtual in `Message` and override this in `MA` and `MB`. Furthermore, you can make `process()` a pure virtual method in `Process` and override this in `PA`. See code below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Message  
{  
    public:  
    const std::string _id;

    Message(std::string id):_id(id) {}

    virtual void print() const = 0;
    virtual void other_fun() const = 0;
};

class MA : public Message  
{ 
    private: double d_; 
    public:  
    MA():Message("MA"), d_(0.0) {}

    virtual void print() const
    {
        std::cout<<"I am MA"<<std::endl;
        std::cout << "I also have a double" << std::endl; 
    }

    virtual void other_fun() const { std::cout << "I am MA specific" << std::endl; }

    void do_hoops () const { std::cout << "Hoop!"<<std::endl;}
};

class MB : public Message  
{  
    private: int i_;
    public:  
    MB():Message("MB"), i_(0) {}

    virtual void print() const
    {
        std::cout<<"I am MB"<<std::endl;
        std::cout << "I also have an int"<<std::endl;
    }

    virtual void other_fun() const { std::cout << "I am MB specific" << std::endl; }

    void do_twist() const { std::cout << "Twist!"<<std::endl; }
};

class Processor  
{  
public:  
    const std::string _id;
    Processor(std::string id) : _id(id){}

    virtual void process(const Message* m) = 0;

};

class PA : public Processor  
{  
    public:  
    PA():Processor("PA") {}

    virtual void process(const Message* m) 
    {
        m->print();
        m->other_fun();
    }
};

int main()  
{  
    Message* m1 = new MA();  
    Message* m2 = new MB();  

    // generic handling of message
    Processor* p1 = new PA();  
    p1->process(m1);
    p1->process(m2);

    // message specific stuff
    dynamic_cast<MA*>(m1)->do_hoops();
    dynamic_cast<MB*>(m2)->do_twist();
    return 0;
}
```

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/kt33y).

No casts are required, the virtual functions will be selected at runtime through dynamic dispatch (virtual table lookup etc.). `Message` and `Process` are abstract base classes ("interfaces") and `MA`, `MB` and `PA` are concrete classes implementing these interfaces. Ideally, you also would factor the `std::string` state out of the `Message` interface, but that's left as an exercise.

Casting would be required if you would call functions that are specific to a derived class, and if you know at runtime that you are in fact calling such a class. This is done through a `dynamic_cast` to the particular derived class your base class pointer is currently pointing to.

Comment: the print methods here are just for example. I actually have different attributes and methods in the each derived message class, which are not feasible (and i don't think correct too) to put in the base class.

Comment: @puneetagrawal You can add other state/functionality into `MA` or `MB` as you see fit, and simply use them in the overridden version of `print()` or other members. But if you ever want to call a member *polymorphically* (i.e. at runtime select the one corresponding to the message type) then such a method needs to be in the base class.

Comment: @puneetagrawal Updated my answer to reflect your problem. I would recommend moving all common code to the abstract base class, and override it where appropriate. Only for those functions that do not have a common interface, which I called `MA::do_hoops()` and `MB::do_twist()`, should you resort to dynamic casting.

Answer (score 1):

The most general solution to your problem is probably the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: That would only solve part of his problem, namely a hierarchy of `Processor` classes. But even for Visitor, you still need to have a common interface for the `Message` classes that you want to visit, so that the Visitor can hook into that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a design flaw. Signature of `Processor::process` suggests it takes a `Message`, then it should not break this promise by trying to access something that is not a public interface of `Message`.

You can make `Process` a template class (host) that inherits from user supplied policies. Policies here are the concrete `Message` classes. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MA
{
    void print ()
    {  
        std::cout << "MA: I'm the interface" << std::endl;
    }

    void printMA ()
    {  
        std::cout << "MA: I'm special" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct MB
{
    void print ()
    {  
        std::cout << "MB: I'm the interface" << std::endl;
    }

    void printMB ()
    {  
        std::cout << "MB: I'm special" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename M>
struct Process :
    public M
{
    void process()
    {  
        M::print();
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Process<MA> p1;
    Process<MB> p2;

    p1.print();     // MA: I'm the interface
    p1.printMA();   // MA: I'm special

    p2.print();     // MB: I'm the interface
    p2.printMB();   // MB: I'm special
}
```

Policies have `print` method that defines its interface. They also have some special methods like `printMA` and `printMB`. Host class (here `Process`) acts as user's interface to the policies. It can use the interface methods from policy classes. Special policy methods can be invoked by the user through host class.

Comment: If he wants to have one Processor that can process messages of many types, then making Process a template class doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You've run into a limitation of C++. What you really want is for the polymorphism to work on the arguments to a method, not just the method that the arguments are called on. It's generally referred to as [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). Unfortunately, while there are some kind-of work-arounds, I haven't seen any perfect ones. That Wikipedia article shows the generally accepted workaround (using the Visitor pattern).

Comment: I agree. I used 'double dispatch' finally to get around this. Now, the only thing is that I need to add a function in MessageProcessor' class, whenever i add a new message type., but i think that is fine.